# Strange Java web application in Eclipse

Tags: java, web, geoserver

I am new to Java web programming and currently working with a Java web project. Although I have searched for days but still not able to figure out what kind of project is it and how to configure to get it run. It has a webapps directory and a web application inside. But the Java code is stored outside and under the root directory.

So what documents should I read to get familiar with this kind of project, and how could I configure to get it run on Tomcat?

[image: eclipse image]

Comment: If it is geoserver you can read the docs at geoserver.org look for developer manual

Comment: Thank you very much, I found it is a java nature project as described in the .project file. But the directory structure is similar to dynamic web app project except for the Java src directory. The thing I don't understand is that I cannot export the project as a .war file for deployment. For now, I just want to deploy it on Tomcat to see how it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `.project` file located in your case at `mapsview/.project` to get more insight about this project. It has builder and natures information which helps you understand what kind of project is.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found it is a java nature project as described in the mapsview/.project file. But the directory structure is similar to dynamic web app project except for the Java src directory. The thing I don't understand is that I cannot export the project as a .war file for deployment. For now, I just want to deploy it on Tomcat to see how it looks like.

Comment: If this is a dyamic web project, you should go to `Right click on the project name in eclipse -> Build Path -> Project Facets -> Dynamic Web Module`  and check mark it and assign a runtime server(tomcat in your case) and run the project